# counterexample to Abel's theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

$D=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|<1\}$. Let $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n(a_n,z\in\Bbb C)$ be a power series, the radius of convergence of $f$ is $1$,   $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n =s$.

1. Give a  power series $f$ such that 
   $$\lim_{D\ni z\to1 }f(z)\ne s$$
2. If $f$ is convergent at every point of the unit circle, is there  such an power series $f$ ?

P.s. the problem is related to [Abel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 1916, Sierpiński constructed an example of a power series with radius of convergence equal to $1$, also converging on every point of the unit circle, **but** with the property that $f$ is unbounded near $z=1$. The construction is not easy, and there may very well be more modern and perhaps more accessible examples. A reprint of the 1916 paper can be found [here, p 282](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/Sierpinski%20Oeuvres%20Choisies%20I.pdf) (in French).

Sierpiński's example settles both your questions.

---

*Added*: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110345/does-a-power-series-converging-everywhere-on-its-circle-of-convergence-define-a) discussion on MO is highly relevant, and contains a simpler construction than  Sierpiński's.